# (Python) Behaviour Of The Slice Function Within A List

Tags: python, slice

I'm learning Python and have a basic grasp of the way Slice works, but there's a particular block of code that I'm having trouble grasping:

```
L = [2,4,6,8,0]

L[0:3] = [2,4,6,8]

print L[4]
```

The output of this is 8, which I find strange; I'd expect it to still be 0 as I read the second line as "transform the first 4 elements of the list into 2,4,6,8." This would still leave a list of [2,4,6,8,0], which is obviously not happening. I'd be grateful if anyone could explain why Slice is behaving this way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> L = [2,4,6,8,0]
>>> L[0:3] = [2,4,6,8]
>>> L
[2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0]
```

This changes the list,`L[0:3]` is `[2, 4, 6]`,so you append another 8 after 6,that's why the forth value is `8` now:

```
>>> L[4]
8
```

Have a look at this picture:

[image]

So maybe what you want is `L[0:4]` or `L[:4]`.Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was thinking that 0:3 was the first FOUR elements, I didn't realize that the 3 wasn't included. Thank you for the clear answer, I'll accept it soon!

Comment: Yep, timer just ran down. Thank you to everyone that cleared that up!

Answer (score 2):

The output is `8` because when you're doing:

```
L[0:3] = [2,4,6,8]
```

You're adding an extra `8` at the end of the list `[2,4,6,8]`:

```
L[0:3] = [2,4,6,8]
print(L)
```

The length of `L[0:3]` is 3, and you're assigning 4 values to it. That's why this is happening.

Output:

> [2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0]

As you can see, `L[4]` is now 8

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
L = [2,4,6,8,0]
L[0:4] = [2,4,6,8]
print L[4]
```

to get 0

Because if

```
L = [2,4,6,8,0]
L[0:3]
```

refers to

```
[2,4,6]
```

and

```
L[0:4]
```

refers to

```
[2,4,6,8]
```

So in your example i think you want L[0:4] so that you can transform them into the new values